# Who designed the closing credits for Love & Mercy?

Tags: production, credits, love-and-mercy

I'm trying to find the name of the design company (or individual) responsible for the credit sequence of this film.

I see "Graphic Artist" is listed in the credits as Ellen Lampl... But I don't know enough about film production to determine if that job title encompasses the design of credits.

I also see [CHIPs given company credit for "Titles"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0903657/companycredits?ref_=tt_dt_co)... but again, not sure if this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the website for the graphic design company known as CHIPs (Brooklyn, NY). In their [online portfolio](http://chips.nyc/archive/) they show the titles/credits for Love and Mercy.